# Access Dictionary (DCSDictionary​Ref) on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to access the word definitions in the integrated dictionary. As shown here: [nshipster.com/dictionary-services/](http://nshipster.com/dictionary-services/)
But this seems only possible on Mac OS X and not on iOS.
Is there a way to do the same on iOS or can I only use "UIReferenceLibraryViewController"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not built in way to do this, outside of `UIReferenceLibraryViewController` on iOS. You could always use your own dictionary files (either freely available ones or licensed) and create your own definition methods if it was important to you.